# aurelia publishing and installing components via jspm and github

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to figure out how to publish and install components for aurelia via jspm and github.

I have a test component at:
https://github.com/caperavensoftware/pragma-tabsheet

I created a new project and install this component via jspm as:

```
jspm install pragma-tabsheet=github:caperavensoftware/pragma-tabsheet
```

in my welcome view I require and use it

```
<template>
    <require from="pragma-tabsheet"></require>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>

    <pragma-tab-sheet>
        <div id="tab1" data-tab="Tab 1"><h2>Tab 1</h2></div>
        <div id="tab2" data-tab="Tab 2"><h2>Tab 2</h2></div>
        <div id="tab3" data-tab="Tab 3"><h2>Tab 3</h2></div>
    </pragma-tab-sheet>
</template>
```

But when running it i get a error where the controls template is not being loaded from the right path.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/caperavensoftware/pragma-tabsheet@master.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Looking a the networks tab in chrome debugging the javascript files are loading correctly but the aurelia template is not.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

I also tried adding it as a plugin:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()
            .developmentLogging()
            .plugin('pragma-tabsheet');

        aurelia.start().then(() => {
            aurelia.setRoot();
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

but that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: I also tried it as a feature but it gave me the same problem

Comment: its not a feature, its a plugin. we'll need a lot more information. particularly, when loading it as a plugin, what is the output, and what does the corresponding line in your systemjs look like. for specific help requests, send me a message on http://gitter.im/davismj

Comment: i created a repository that shows off the problem.
https://github.com/caperavensoftware/jspmtests

after cloning you need to do the normal npm install, jspm install and typings install

build the code: "gulp build:all"
and run it "gulp: serve"